# Is there any option to include a Python script, which is hosted on a online webhost?

Tags: python

I am currently doing a little python project, and I am wondering if there is any way that I can import a script which is hosted on my web page. The script includes some vars like

```
CurrentV = 'The current version is 1.2'
```

...so I don't need to text everyone that I made a new version. They can see it then in their scripts, because it's way faster to just update the version on my web host.

I tried it that way:

```
import requests
oimport = requests.get('https://website.com/version.py')
from oimport.content import CurrentV

print(CurrentV)
print('your current version is 1.1')
```

But it's not working that way.

Comment: How is it "not working"?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lukas\Desktop\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    from oimport.content import CurrentV
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oimport'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can make this work is to write the "module" to disk and then import it. For example:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import sys

oimport = requests.get('https://website.com/version.py')

module_path = "./modules"

# Write the code to modules/version.py
with open(f"{module_path}/version.py", "w") as module_file:
  module_file.write(module_path)

# Make sure our path in sys.path
sys.path.append(module_path)

from version import CurrentV
```

THIS OPENS UP A CAN OF WORMS IN THE FORM OF CODE INJECTION! but it does/should do what you need it to do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but its sadly not the solution i was looking for